# Technical term to denote opposite of dependency injection?

Tags: terminology, refactoring, dependency-injection

This is more of a nomenclature (technical writing) rather than a purely technical question. I am trying to write a refactoring proposal (and get it assigned to myself) centered around expanding dependency injection in our application. While we do use *Spring* for autowiring beans, there are still instances that instantiate beans using `MyClass obj = new MyClass(...)`, which could totally be injected. I would like to make my proposal use elegant nomenclature and refer to the design pattern opposite of DI with a proper term.

Is "tight coupling" an adequate term that stands as an antonym to DI?

Comment: Yes, *coupling* describes both the act of using explicit class names in other classes and the resulting state of a code base.

Comment: No, tight coupling only describes the property of the resulting code, not the opposite of DI. You can use DI and still have tight coupling for completely different reasons.

Comment: Agreed that [DI and tight coupling are not opposites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541952/how-exactly-does-dependency-injection-reduce-coupling/4542541#4542541).

Comment: @EricKing show off.  +1 by the way.

Comment: _"Dependency suction"_.

Comment: The opposite of dependency injection is called 'programming'.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy Ha .. I like that! But, if you want to go that route, wouldn't it be "dependency expulsion?"

Comment: "inversion of control" vs "procedural"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Is "tight coupling" an adequate term that stands as an antonym to DI?

No.  Tight coupling is much more than what dependency injection deals with.

Dependency injection externalizes a decision of implementation.  This goes a long way to decouple but coupling is more than just this.

> Technical term to denote opposite of dependency injection?

A good antonym for dependency injection is **hard coding a dependency**.  When you construct (use new or directly use some factory) inside a behavior object you've smushed together two different concerns. A service locator helps decouple but leaves you coupled to the service locator itself.

Coupling is more than just [separating construction and behavior](https://portal.netobjectives.com/reading-path/core-developer-skills/core-developer-skills-principles/).  If I have 101 methods that have to be called in some particular order from class A to class B I'm tightly coupled.  Doesn't matter how wonderfully separated construction and behavior are.

Coupling is a measure the interdependence of the two objects.  Anything that contributes to making it difficult to make changes in one without impacting the other is contributing to coupling.  Dependency injection helps with this but it is not all of this.

Comment: Yes, hard coding (a dependency), as opposed to injecting it (at runtime) is exactly what I was going to suggest, too, you just were a little bit quicker than me.

Comment: @DocBrown I sometimes wish this place didn't put so much emphasis on being fast.  I'd like to hear how you'd put it.

Comment: Good answer - dependency injection does not imply decoupling. Believing otherwise leads down a bad road

Comment: @CandiedOrange Maybe someone should suggest in meta that answers be remain hidden for a period of time. And/Or that votes be hidden from public view for `N` hours... Or until an answer is selected. I know *I'm* not entirely objective when one answer already has 10 votes and the other 5 answers have none!

Comment: @svidgen search "fastest gun in the west" on meta.  The issue already has a long history.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I see a small handful of things on meta.p.se, but no practical suggestions!

Comment: Speaking of meta we shouldn't do this here.  Feel free to chat with me on [the-whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)

Comment: So wait. What's the actual answer to the top-level question. What *is* the opposite of *dependency injection?*

Comment: I don't think there is a single thing that is the _opposite_ of dependency injection. DI is but one of multiple strategies for dependency management.

Comment: @svidgen aside from what I've bolded in the answer, [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a specific way to follow the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) which, according to it's own explination, is the inversion of: "the way some people may think about object-oriented design, dictating that both high- and low-level objects must depend on the same abstraction".

Comment: @CandiedOrange Actually, the bolding helps a lot to clarify which part of your answer is your actual answer. If that makes any sense... Though, I think I disagree with your answer then!

Comment: @svidgen Antonyms are like synonyms in that there is rarely only one of them.  I really didn't want to focus on that as much as on teasing apart coupling and dependency injection.

Comment: @DocBrown careful wording: dependency injection does not strictly describe the practice of creating objects "reflectively" at runtime. All objects are created at runtime. Dependency injection refers to the requirement that the existence of one object explicitly depends upon the existence of some other object. The canonical way to convey such a requirement is via a constructor parameter. There are fancy frameworks that use runtime meta-programming to try and hide the fact that an object with 15 different dependencies is sloppy. But it's certainly not a requirement that one be used.

Comment: @DavidCowden: I did not describe DI as the practice of creating objects (reflectively) at run time, not even close.

Comment: @DocBrown you presented a dichotomy between *hard coding* a dependency and *injecting* one at runtime, *"Yes, hard coding (a dependency), as opposed to injecting it (at runtime) is exactly what I was going to suggest, too, ..."* That's ambiguous at best. I can't read your mind. So I commented for future readers with the intention of elaborating on the distinction (benefit of doubt to you) and because I know some people will take that to mean "DI is when you use @Inject". If you agree with me, great. I don't give a rat's ass what you think you meant in your wise old head.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, **Dependency Injection** only really opposes ***NOT* Dependency Injection** -- and therefore any dependency management strategy that *isn't* Dependency Injection.

[Unwanted] coupling, though not exactly an orthogonal issue, can either occur or be mitigated either way. These are both coupled to `DependencyClass`:

```
public DependencyInjectedConstructor(DependencyClass dep) {
  dep.do();
}

public DependencyLookupConstructor() {
  var dep = new DependencyClass();
  dep.do();
}
```

`DependencyLookupConstructor` is coupled to a particular `DependencyClass` in this case. But, they're *both* coupled to `DependencyClass`. The real evil, if there is one here, isn't the coupling necessarily, it's that `DependencyLookupConstructor` needs to change if `DependencyClass` suddenly needs its own dependencies injected<sup>1</sup>.

However, this constructor/class is even *more* loosely coupled:

```
public DependencyLocatingConstructor() {
  var dep = ServiceLocator.GetMyDoer();
  dep.do();
}
```

If you're working in C#, the above will permit your `ServiceLocator` to return *anything* when `GetMyDoer()` is invoked, as long as it has can `do()` what `DependencyLocatingConstructor` has it `do()`. You get the benefit of compile-time signature validation without even being coupled to a complete interface<sup>2</sup>.

So, pick your poison.

**But basically,** if there's a concrete "opposite" of Dependency Injection, it would be something else in the realm of "Dependency Management Strategies." Amongst others, if you used any of the following in conversation, I'd recognize it as being *NOT* Dependency Injection:

- Service Locator Pattern
- Dependency Locator / Location
- Direct object/dependency construction
- Hidden dependency
- "Not Dependency Injection"

---

<sup>1. Ironically, some of the problems that DI solves at higher levels are sort of a result of [over-]using DI in the lower levels. I've had the pleasure of working on codebases with unnecessary complexity *all over* as a result of accommodating the handful of places where that complexity actually helped ... I'm admittedly biased by bad exposure.</sup>

<sup>2. Using service location also permits you to easily specify different dependencies of the same type by their functional role *from the invoking code*, while still being largely agnostic about how the dependency is built. Suppose you need to resolve `User` or `IUser` for different purposes: E.g., `Locator.GetAdministrator()` versus `Locator.GetAuthor()` -- or whatever. My code can ask for what it needs *functionally* without even knowing what interfaces it supports.</sup>

Comment: The salvation for `DependencyInjectedConstructor(DependencyClass dep)` is that DependencyClass could be an interface or abstract class.  This is why it makes me sad that C# coders use an interface prefix, as in `IDependency`.  As the client, It's really not my business what this Dependency thing is.  As long as I don't construct it, all I have to know is how to talk to it.  What it is is someone else's problem.

Comment: Points being, DI still couples you to that interface, and it doesn't *require* that `DependencyClass` be an abstract interface at all. It *only* requires that the construction/configuration/location logic existing "somewhere else." ... Well, and more pertinently to the question, the point is that DI isn't "the opposite of tight coupling" :)

Comment: Actually ... I may be slightly out of bounds in saying DI necessarily couples you to an interface, even in C#. Though, I've avoided them in C#, I'm under the impression I could also accept `dynamic` parameters. (But not `var` parameters, if memory serves.) So, with DI in C#, I *think* I either have to code against an interface, or I have to totally forgo the compile-time validation.

Comment: Objects are coupled to the interfaces. Whether you use the interface keyword or not.  That's what a proper interface is.  Everything you HAVE to be coupled to.  What you boil away are implementation details and extra stuff you don't need.  We can formalize this by using the interface keyword to let the client tell the world, "All I need is this". But we don't have to. Heck we can do duck typing, well in some languages.

Comment: I'm not sure we're in total disagreement. But, to clarify ... Objects are *internally* coupled to *their own* interfaces, yes. But, the interface itself only imposes dependency-coupling if the interface is explicitly named. In C#, using `dynamic` or `var` and getting an object from a locator let's you ignore the interface and use *any* class that can `do()` what you need, regardless of whether that class implements some `IDoer` interface. In other words, if we have A->B<-C, DI decouples A from C, but it requires both A and C to be coupled to B, and prevents use of D, even if D will `do()`.

Comment: Which again, is just a long way of saying, "No, DI isn't 'the opposite' of tight coupling."

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there's specific, widely accepted industry terminology, but alternatives that come to mind include **internal instance creation**, **internal dependency creation**, **local dependencies**, or **locally scoped dependencies**.

Comment: i like `instance creation` but it is not specific enough.  DI creates instances but by the means of controller and not at the application level.  maybe `internal instance creation`

Answer (score 2):

**Direct Dependency**

Wow asked 6 years ago!  I came to do this page searching for the same answer, and ultimately decided to use the term **Direct Dependency** instead of Hard Coding.

This decision was made because it describes what the injection avoids, by creating an **indirect dependency**.  And after coming up with that definition, I decided to also start using the term **indirect dependency** to describe the general case of injection.

## Reasoning

If i was to provide an object containing functions to a system, this would function as form of injection.  The host or controller would have a direct dependency to the target, and the method would be invoked without a dependency from the target to either.

Target

```
export default {
  setName(name){ }  
}
```

So the common denominator between either exposing a method, or having some method accept an injected parameter by various means, is that the dependency is indirect, and removed from the target.  The target has either a direct dependency or an indirect dependency on something.  Injection is a form of indirect dependency.

Now let's look at the ideal coupling of dependencies, using the mediator pattern.  Using this pattern, we have both direct and indirect dependencies:

Target

```
useMediator().callback = (name) => { myName = name }
```

Host

```
useMediator().callback('foobar')
```

In this example, our target has a direct dependency to the mediator, but publishes its callback to be used an indirect dependency.  The host of our target will also have a direct dependency to the mediator, but an indirect dependency to the client method.  In code-speak, the client and host include the mediator, but not each other.

The bottom line is that there are many ways to implement indirect dependencies, including but not limited to method parameter injection, but only 1 way to implement direct dependencies: by explicitly including them.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **dependency encapsulation**. This expresses the dependency is locked in rather than visiting and leaving again.